# rollback inserted object in java using sprintboot and mongodb

Tags: java, spring-boot

i use spring boot and mongodb
i want to made a @transactional if the user is not inserted i want to delete the car inserted

```
      @Override
        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
        public void save(CarDto carDto,Userdto userDto){
        User user=new User();
        //save object car
            Car car = CareService.save(carDto);
        //setobject inserted
            user.setCar(car);
            user.setPhoneNumber(userDto.getPhoneNumber());
            // here i suppose that UserService.save(User) will return for exemple an exception phone number of the user is already exist
            UserService.save(User); 
}
```

Comment: Mongo doesn't support transactions.

Comment: chrylis  what about this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Comment: Hmm. That's a brand-new feature in 4.2, and I don't believe supported in most clients yet, including Spring Data.